# How to compare two regexps?

Tags: javascript, regex, compare

Why do

```
console.log(/a/ == /a/);
```

and

```
var regexp1 = /a/;
var regexp2 = /a/;
console.log(regexp1 == regexp2);
```

both return `false`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
String(regexp1) === String(regexp2))
```

You are getting false because those two are different objects.

Comment: error.errorVal.requiredPattern.toString() == ("^(0|[1-9]\d*)(.\d+)?$").toString()
false // not working
error.errorVal.requiredPattern
"^(0|[1-9]\d*)(.\d+)?$"

Comment: I have tried to convert to string but it is not working ..

Comment: If using `new` to create the String, you need to call valueOf since an Object is being created (rather than a primitive String literal) - e.g. (new String(regexp1)).valueOf() === (new String(regexp2)).valueOf()

Answer (score 14):

**"Problem":**

`regex` is an `object`- a **reference type**, so the **comparsion is done by reference**, and those are two different objects.

```
console.log(typeof /a/); // "object"
```

> If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

**Solution:**

```
​var a = /a/;
var b = /a/;
console.log(​​​a.toString() === b.toString()); // true! yessss!
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LQnKt/)

Another "hack" to force the `toString()` on the `regex`es is:

```
console.log(a + "" === b + "");​
```

Comment: error.errorVal.requiredPattern.toString() == ("^(0|[1-9]\d*)(.\d+)?$").toString() false // not working error.errorVal.requiredPattern "^(0|[1-9]\d*)(.\d+)?$"

Comment: it is not working when i use reactive form error and try to match with same pattern which i inserted in the validators

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess - but doesn't JavaScript create a `RegExp` object for your regex, and therefore because you have created two different objects (even though they have the same "value") they're actually different?

Answer (score 2):

For primitive data types like int, string, boolean javascript knows what to compare, but for objects like date or regex that operator only looks at the place in memory, because you define your regexes independently they have two different places in memory so they are not equal.